# Cant get my integers to add to get correct output

Tags: java, input, mismatch

so I am trying to do my homework, this being the question:

Write a program that prompts the user to read two integers and displays their sum. If anything but an integer is passed as input, your program should catch the InputMismatchException that is thrown and prompt the user to input another number by printing "Please enter an integer."

Below is the sample run and what I am supposed to test.

```
SAMPLE RUN #1: java InputMismatch

Enter an integer: 2.5↵ 

Please enter an integer↵ 

Enter an integer: 4.6↵ 

Please enter an integer↵ 

Enter an integer: hello!↵

Please enter an integer↵ 

Enter an integer:7↵ 

Enter an integer:5.6↵

Please enter an integer↵

Enter an integer:9.4↵ 

Please enter an integer ↵

Enter an integer:10↵ 

17↵
```

When I am testing my code and putting in the integers, it works as it is supposed to, however, I am stuck on getting the integers to add together when both inputs are entered correctly. What am I doing wrong?

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestInputMismatch {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

      int num1 = 0;
      int num2 = 0;
      boolean isValid = false;

      while (!isValid) {
         try {
            System.out.print("Enter an integer: ");
            int number = input.nextInt();

            System.out.println("The number entered is " + number);

            boolean continueInput = false;
         }
         catch (InputMismatchException ex) {
            System.out.println("Try again. (" + "Incorrect input: an integer is required)");
            input.nextLine();
         }

      } 
      System.out.println((num1 + num2));
   }
}
```

Comment: In this code snippet, assignments to num1 and num2 are missing. both num1 and num2 are initialized to 0 and no assignments after that. Also the while loop has condition !isValid, could not see where isValid is getting changed to terminate the loop. So it looks like infinite loop as of now.
You may want to show full program text.

Comment: To clear up some confusion that was a sample run. I am only required to enter those numbers when I am testing the program. The result should be that only the correct integers are added. Hence the 17 at the end of the sample run. When a decimal is entered, my code kicks it back and says it is incorrect, the problem that I am having is getting the integers that are correct to add together.

Comment: You could use Integer objects instead and initialise them to `null`  - if not `null` then they have been correctly initialised

Comment: I can't find where the string "Please enter an integer' is printed.

Answer (score 1):

try adding another condition to your while and putting the numbers in an array.

```
int[] numbers = new int[2];
```

and change this in your while loop:

```
int count = 0;
 while (!isValid && count <2) {
    try {
        System.out.print("Enter an integer: ");
        numbers[count] = input.nextInt();
        count++;
        System.out.println("The number entered is " + number);

        boolean continueInput = false;
    }
    catch (InputMismatchException ex) {
        System.out.println("Try again. (" + "Incorrect input: an integer is required)");
        input.nextLine();
    }

}
```

Hope that helped.

Comment: what is `boolean continueInput = false;` for ?

Comment: How is `while (!isValid` used ?

Answer (score 1):

Check with this approach:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] numArray = new int[2];
    int count = 0;

    while (count <= 1) {
        try {
            System.out.print("Enter an integer: ");
            int number = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println("The number entered is " + number);
            numArray[count] = number;
            count++;
        } catch (InputMismatchException ex) {
            System.out.println("Try again. (" + "Incorrect input: an integer is required)");
            input.nextLine();
        }
    }
    int num1 = numArray[0];
    int num2 = numArray[1];
    System.out.println((num1 + num2));
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I could not understand what I was doing wrong!

Comment: @Inez2454 you havent assign your inputs to num1 and num2. This isValid boolean flag is useless because you are not assign any value to it inside the code. Better to debug and check what are the wrong with your code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to stitch together the logic. As you are taking 2 numbers 2 flags will ensure you got correct input for both variables. Also both flags ensure you are taking input correctly for num1 or num2 when an exception occurs.
If you need to input n arbitrary integers, then you may want to use dynamic collections and add numbers to collection.

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

      int num1 = 0;
      int num2 = 0;
      boolean num1Valid = false;
      boolean num2Valid = false;

      while (num1Valid==false || num2Valid==false) {
         try {
           if(num1Valid == false) {
            System.out.print("Enter an integer for num1: ");
            num1 = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println("The number entered for num1 is " + num1);
            num1Valid = true;
           }

           if(num2Valid == false) {
            System.out.print("Enter an integer for num2: ");
            num2 = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println("The number entered for num2 is " + num2);
            num2Valid = true;
           }
         }
         catch (InputMismatchException ex) {
            System.out.println("Try again. (" + "Incorrect input: an integer is required)");
            input.nextLine();
         }
      }
      input.close()
      System.out.println((num1 + num2));
   }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help as well. It makes sense to stitch the logic together, I just wasn't sure how to go about that the right way.

Answer (score 0):

You need capture the exception, in this case you can using e.getMessage()

```
public class TestInputMismatch {

public static void main(String[] args) {

     Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

     int num1=0, number=0;
     boolean isValid = false;

     while (!isValid) {
        try {
            System.out.print("Enter an integer: ");
            number = input.nextInt();
            if(number > 0) {
                System.out.println("The number entered is " + number);
            }

            num1 += number;

            System.out.println("are would you like continue the program? Y or 
             N ");
            String condition = input.next();

            if(condition.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
                isValid = false;
            } else {
                isValid = true;
            }
         }
         catch (InputMismatchException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            System.out.println("You cannot type words");
            isValid = true;
         }

     }
     System.out.println("Result = " + num1);
     input.close();
 }
}
```

in another case do you can use the method matches using expression language

**saw example below:**

```
   if(valor.matches("[0-9]*"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the two numbers inside the try block

import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestInputMismatch {

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

  int num1 = 0;
  int num2 = 0;
  boolean isValid = false;

  while (!isValid) {
     try {
        System.out.print("Enter an integer: ");
        num1 = input.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter an integer: ");
        num2 = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("The numbers you  entered are " + num1 + ","+num2);

        int sum = num1+num2;
        System.out.println("The sum Of the numbers you entered is: "+ sum);

        boolean continueInput = false;
     }
     catch (InputMismatchException ex) {
        System.out.println("Try again. (" + "Incorrect input: an integer is required)");
        input.nextLine();
     }

  } 
  System.out.println((num1 + num2));
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
public class InputMismatch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] numArray = new int[2];
        int count = 0;
        while (count <= 1) {
            try {
                System.out.print("Enter an integer:");
                int number = input.nextInt();
                numArray[count] = number;
                count++;
            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                System.out.println("Please enter an integer.");
                input.nextLine();
            }
        }
        System.out.println(numArray[0] + numArray[1]);
        
    }
}
```